# Yii with() method

Tags: php, yii

I got this code in Yii:

```
 $comment = Comment::model()->with(array('issue'=> array(
               'condition'=>'project_id = 1')))->findAll(array( 
                      'order' => 't.create_time DESC', 'limit' => 2, ));
```

when I changed "'limit'=>2" to "'limit' =>null" it passed.

As I understand that if I changed those values the equivalent query will change to:

```
SELECT tbl_comment . * , tbl_issue . *    FROM tbl_comment
LEFT JOIN tbl_issue ON tbl_issue.id = tbl_comment.issue_id WHERE tbl_issue.project_id = 1
LIMIT null
```

I have try on mysql command line and the above query didn't pass on mysql, but it did pass when I use the CODE above in Yii.

So, could you tell me why did this conflic occur?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new relationship in Comment model like this:

```
class Comment extends CActiveRecord
{
    ......

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'issues'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Issue', 'issue_id'),
        );
    }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
 $comment = Comment::model()->with('issues');
```

Anyway your table structure looks a bit strange:  does a Comment have only one issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing mysql then their is no sense to use null in limit as "limit null".
So when you set

```
"limit"=>null
```

in condition, Yii does not include it in the query & query is executed without limit.

Please have a at logs in runtime folder, mysql queries are logged there.
Look application.log file for logs.

If your mysql queries are not logged there then change your config file main.php as following

```
// db configuration
'db'=>array(
  'connectionString'=>...
    'enableParamLogging'=>true,
    'enableProfiling'=>true,
),

// log configuration
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info, profile, packages.solr.ASolrConnection',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                 /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                 */

            ),
        ),
```

Now your queries will be logged there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had a look at application.php in RUNTIME folder (that is inside the PROTECTED folder). However can't find any mysql queries in this log file. Is that file the one you mentioned above?

Comment: If you're using apache2 (including LAMP/MAMP/WAMP/XAMP/MAPPstack etc) check your .../apache2/logs/error.log (or error_log) file.